# Flutter video player not initialized

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use Video Player but it doesn't seem to initialize.
Here is my code:

```
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api- 
              docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4')
        ..initialize().then((_) {
           setState(() {});
       }
    );
  }

  Widget _playView(BuildContext context) {
    if (_controller != null && _controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return Expanded(
       child: Container(
         child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
       ),
     );
    } else {
       return Text('Loading video');
    }
  }
  //end of _playView
```

The play `_playView` is called inside A `Row()` widget (into the main Container of the page)
It always goes in the `else` statement and so i always see the 'Loading video' Text.
I don't get any errors. I've tried the code from various sources (docs, youtube) but nothing works.
I've also added the Internet permission in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.
The plugin used is this one https://pub.dev/packages/video_player

Comment: I'd recommend adding the code as a code snippet instead of a screenshot. What's the package you're using for playing the video? Where are you calling the `_playView` method?

Comment: @AhmadF I edited the question accordingly, with the info and corrections you suggested

Comment: @AhmadF Also I noticed that on my real phone the video is loaded and played correctly so it's probably not a problem of the plugin or the code. Could there be an issue with the Emulator?

Comment: @akamzel Tested your code, it's working fine on my emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue when trying to play the video in the `initState` method after initializing the `_controller`:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4')
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        setState(() {});
        _controller.play(); // adding this
      });
  }
```

It always goes to the `else` statement (`return Text('Loading video');`).

---

To resolve it, I declared a custom flag for notifying the `_controller` initialization instead of relying on its (`_controller.value.isInitialized`) property:

```
bool _controllerInitialized = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4')
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        setState(() {
          _controllerInitialized = true;
        });
        _controller.play();
      });
  }
```

Hence, you could render the video player when `_controllerInitialized` is `true`:

```
_controllerInitialized
          ? AspectRatio( // here is your Expanded widget...
              aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
              child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
            )
          : const Text('Loading video'),
```

Note that the video will play automatically, you could stop it by removing `_controller.play();` from the `initState` method.

Comment: today it actually worked even with my code, maybe the emulator had some issue yesterday and was not working. Your code worked as a charm though so thank you very much!

Comment: @akamzel glad to help. To confirm, note that my answer helps in case you want to directly play the video after loading (initializing) it.